# How to delete existing controls in angular?

Tags: angular, ngfor

[image: Example]I have generated angular tabs dynamically using ngFor directive.

when array gets update, instead of deleting old tabs they get append with new tabs.

Comment: please provide sample code in a [mcve] and read  [ask]

Comment: Please add the component code responsible for creating the tabs.

Comment: <tab [tabTitle]="line" *ngFor="let line of lines">
    <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</tab>     Please have the code example  above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are updating the tabs Array but this might help you.

```
  tabs = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];

  addTab(selectAfterAdding: boolean) {
    this.tabs.push('Fourth');
  }

  removeTab(index: number) {
    this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Comment: <tab [tabTitle]="line" *ngFor="let line of lines">
    <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</tab>     Please have the code example  above. I am updating the tabs array like this